# DynamoDB vs GAE Datastore: Which one is cheaper for json key-value store?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, amazon-dynamodb

I need to store many sha1 keyed json objects into DB

I don't want to admin the DB, so I am considering DynamoDB or GAE Datastore or similar things.

Assume performance or other factors can be ignored.

Which (DynamoDB or GAE Datastore) one will be cheaper?

I have read this http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/03/dynamodb-price-reduction-and-new-reserved-capacity-model.html

But pricing for GAE and AWS is too complicated and hard to compare.

Anyone who have experience to use both?

Please share with us. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both services have a free tier and then you pay after that. They both meter both storage and operations. But, they meter operations differently. With DynamoDB you provision units of capacity per second and are metered hourly. Google charges for number of operations (per month?). You need to look at (1) how much data you're planning on storing, and (2) how many operations per second you think you're going to do.